# Javascript objects and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object

I have this code:

```
 jsonObj = [];
 $("#test").find('.data').each(function() {

    var description = $(this).find('.description').val();
    var food = $(this).find('.food').val();

    item = {}
    item ["description"] = description;
    item ["food"] = food;

    jsonObj.push(item);
});
```

Internet explorer 11 inserts empty/null values.
of-course it works well in chrome firefox or even in edge

Comment: "inserts empty/null values" — Where? Given what input? How / when are you testing this?

Comment: I can verify the OP's claim about IE11 with this: https://jsfiddle.net/vdnhxhLo/

Comment: Side note: `jsonObj` is an odd name for a variable whose value is not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Your `jsonObj` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the issue using your code [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdnhxhLo/) in IE11.

The problem is that you haven't declared `item`, and so you're using a global `item` (thanks to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)<sup>1</sup>), which is predefined in IE11 as a native function you can't overwrite or add properties to ([this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536460(v=vs.85).aspx), according to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535873(v=vs.85).aspx)). It's not predefined (or is overwritable) in other browsers.

The lesson here is: **Declare your variables**. :-) If you do that, it works on IE11 as well ([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdnhxhLo/1/)):

```js
var jsonObj = []; // ***
 $("#test").find('.data').each(function() {

    var description = $(this).find('.description').val();
    var food = $(this).find('.food').val();

    var item = {}  // ***
    item ["description"] = description;
    item ["food"] = food;

    jsonObj.push(item);
});
$("<pre>").text("Result: " + JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2)).appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="data">
    <input type="text" class="description" value="description1">
    <input type="text" class="food" value="food1">
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <input type="text" class="description" value="description2">
    <input type="text" class="food" value="food2">
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <input type="text" class="description" value="description3">
    <input type="text" class="food" value="food3">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

---

*<sup>1</sup> That's a post on my anemic little blog.*